# In Javascript, my 1-by-1 increment is going 1,3,6,10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a File Upload script called Simple Photo Manager. When I upload a few images and I want to delete some of them, I have to create a variable numDeleted (number of images deleted)

I will describe the outcome and then I will show you the code.
Please le me know if you know why this is happening

The outcome is:

-Scenario: Three uploaded images are displayed

```
-I click 1st Delete, div is successfully hidden, then: alert('1')
-I click 2nd Delete, div is successfully hidden, then: alert('2'), alert('3')
-I click 3rd Delete, div is successfully hidden, then: alert('4'), alert('5'),alert('6')
```

This is the function that is exec when an image is uploaded:

```
function setUploadedImage(imgSrc, fileTempName, divId) {
    var par = window.document;

    var images = par.getElementById('images_container');
    numDeleted = 0;

    var imgdiv = par.getElementById(divId);
    // all its attributes here...

    var image_new = par.createElement('img');
    // all its attributes here...

    var image_label = par.createElement('input');
    // all its attributes here...

    var image_hidden = par.createElement('input');
    // all its attributes here...

    var image_name = par.createElement('input');
    // all its attributes here...

    var image_del_link = par.createElement('input');
    // all its attributes here...

    var br = par.createElement('br');

    imgdiv.appendChild(image_new);
    imgdiv.appendChild(image_hidden);

    imgdiv.appendChild(image_name);
    imgdiv.appendChild(br);
    imgdiv.appendChild(image_del_link);

    $(".deleteit").click(function(){
             $(this).parent().hide();
             numDeleted = numDeleted + 1;
         alert(numDeleted);
        })
```

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in your code? You may understand why event is fired looking the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to make some assumptions because of some missing information, but I assume the `image_del_link` element has the `'deleteit'` class.

If so, you're binding new handlers to all elements in the DOM with that class. So every time a new one is set up, redundant handlers are added to the ones that already exist.

Change this...

```
$(".deleteit").click(function(){
```

to this...

```
$(image_del_link).click(function(){
```

...in order to bind only to the newly created element.

---

Or a better solution is to use event delegation with the `.on()` method...

```
$('#images_container').on('click', '.deleteit', function(){...
```

This should be placed outside your `setUploadedImage()` function so that it's only run once.

Any elements with the `.deleteit` class inside the `images_container` that are clicked, will trigger the handler placed on `images_container`.

---

If you're using an older version of jQuery, use `.delegate`, instead of `.on()`...

```
$('#images_container').delegate('.deleteit', 'click', function(){...
```

---

If you're using a *really* old version, then upgrade.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I need to pay more attention to those class calls!.. I will look into that delegate function. Never heard of it. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are **adding** a click handler to **every** element with class `deleteit` each time you upload something new.

```
$(".deleteit").click(function(){  // This is added to *every* existing delete button
     $(this).parent().hide();
     numDeleted = numDeleted + 1;
     alert(numDeleted);
});
```

So after the second upload, the first item has the first click handler, and another one.

`.click` does not replace existing handlers.  You could remove them first, but that is a little heavy handed.  Instead, just target the new one you created.

I think you want this:

```
$(image_del_link).click(function(){
     $(this).parent().hide();
     numDeleted = numDeleted + 1;
     alert(numDeleted);
});
```

But you didn't put the delete link code, so I don't know if this is the right element.

**Note**: I would look into doing everything with jQuery.  You are creating elements with plain javascript calls.  Mixing and matching will end up being confusing in the long run:

```
var images = $('#images_container');

var imgdiv = $('#'+divId);

var image_new = $('<img>').attr({id: 'myID', src: 'http://mySrc'});
// OR:
var image_new = $('<img src="http://mySrc" id="myID">');

var image_label = $('<input>').attr({...});

var image_hidden = $('<input>').attr({...});

var image_name = $('<input>').attr({...});

var image_del_link = $('<input>').attr({...});

imgdiv.append(image_new);
imgdiv.append(image_hidden);

imgdiv.append(image_name);
imgdiv.append('<br>');
imgdiv.append(image_del_link);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, but it seems that I have to put the $() operator otherwise, it doesn't work.
Thanks a lot for your help. Regards